# ADO.NET error trying to run Python Script in PowerBI

Tags: python, anaconda, powerbi

I have Anaconda which runs this simple script fine:

```
import pandas as pd
data = [['Alex',10],['Bob',12],['Clarke',13]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['Name','Age'],dtype=float)
print (df)
```

It runs from both Anaconda promprt and normal command prompt, as the path is set to include the Anaconda3 folder.

Trying to use PowerBI, following the Microsoft example, I get:

> Details: "ADO.NET: Python script error. Traceback (most recent call
>   last):   File "PythonScriptWrapper.PY", line 2, in 
>       import os, pandas, matplotlib   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas__init__.py", line
>   19, in 
>       "Missing required dependencies {0}".format(missing_dependencies)) ImportError: Missing required dependencies ['numpy']

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar error (my missing dependency was **xlrd**). To get my python script to run in PowerBI I had to install the missing dependency using pip:

```
C:\>pip install xlrd
```

My PowerBI points to my Python distribution installed in C:\Python (yours most likely points to Anaconda).

I would try installing **numpy** through Anaconda and then re-run your Python Script in Power BI.

Answer (score 0):

**1. Add Anaconda to System Environment Variable Path list:**

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Scripts
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Library\bin

[Environment variable should be above other python installs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FvpFC.jpg)

**2. Updated/Reinstall PowerBI if the erron still persists.**

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that the solution is launching the Power BI Desktop executable from the Anaconda Prompt after activating the environment in which you want to run the Python script.

The long one is described in this [blog post](https://medium.com/microsoftazure/fixing-ado-net-error-trying-to-run-python-script-in-power-bi-83e4b98cba8d).

Answer (score 0):

**Follow following steps:**

 Prerequisite: You must Download Anaconda3 for windows

1. Open Power
2. Files-> Options-> select python script->

In that, 
i. Detected Python home directory-> other-> select path of anaconda3
ii. Detected Python IDE  select Default OS program for .py file
iii. Click ok

then you are ready to import py script

(`C:\ProgramData\anaconda3`)

[Power BI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f80Lm.png)